# How to filter an array using forEach() inside filter() - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and I'd like to filter it based on another array. If `filters` object value is only one, I can use only `filter`, but if there are one more values in `filters` object, nothing show. So use `forEach` inside the filter and wanted to return fit values. Could you please help me what the issue is? Thanks

Expected result:

```
[
    {
        "tags": [
            "madewithout__gluten",
            "madewithout__nuts",
        ],
        "metafields": "Side"
    }
]
```

```js
const data = [
    {
        "tags": [
            "madewithout__gluten",
            "madewithout__nuts",
        ],
        "metafields": "Side"
    },
    {
        "tags": [
            "madewithout__gluten",
        ],
        "metafields": "Side"
    },
    {
        "tags": [
            "madewithout__nuts"
        ],
        "metafields": "Side"
    }
]

const filters = ['gluten', 'nuts'] 

const result = data.filter((v) => {
  filters.forEach((tag) => {
    if(!v.tags.includes(`madewithout__${tag}`))
      return;
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the semantics of the data you provided, you want to check if all `filters` are contained in `tags`:

```js
const result = data.filter((v) => 
    filters.every((tag) => v.tags.includes(`madewithout__${tag}`))
)
```

```js
const data = [
    {
        "tags": [
            "madewithout__gluten",
            "madewithout__nuts",
        ],
        "metafields": "Side"
    },
    {
        "tags": [
            "madewithout__gluten",
        ],
        "metafields": "Side"
    },
    {
        "tags": [
            "madewithout__nuts"
        ],
        "metafields": "Side"
    }
]

const filters = ['gluten', 'nuts'] 

const result = data.filter((v) => 
    filters.every((tag) => v.tags.includes(`madewithout__${tag}`))
)

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `.forEach`, use `.some`

```
const result = data.filter((v) => {
  return !filters.some((tag) => !v.tags.includes(`madewithout__${tag}`))
});
```

```js
const data = [{
    "tags": [
      "madewithout__gluten",
      "madewithout__nuts",
    ],
    "metafields": "Side"
  },
  {
    "tags": [
      "madewithout__gluten",
    ],
    "metafields": "Side"
  },
  {
    "tags": [
      "madewithout__nuts"
    ],
    "metafields": "Side"
  }
]

const filters = ['gluten', 'nuts']

const result = data.filter((v) => {
  return !filters.some((tag) => !v.tags.includes(`madewithout__${tag}`))
});
console.log(result);
```

---

**Issues with your code**

1. `Array.forEach` does not return anything. So your return does not break loop or return value.
2. Your `Array.filter` does not have `return` statement. Due to this, by default everything is falsy (return undefined) and hence empty array

Comment: Thanks for your post, but your result is not same as my expected result.  I wanted AND result

Comment: Yup realised the mistake in condition late. Ideal implementation is in @some-user's answer but do not want to make his answer void, so adding alternate in mine